# Prove that a submodule $A$ of a module $X$ over $R$ is a direct summand if the quotient module $X/A$ is free

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

> Prove that a submodule $A$ of a module $X$ over $R$ is a direct
>   summand if the quotient module $X/A$ is free

If the quotient module is free, then the quotient module $X/A$ is such that, for a set $B$ and a function $f:B\to X/A$, for every module $X$ and every function $g:B\to X$ there exists a unique homomorphism $h:X/A\to X$ such that $g = h\circ f$.

Since we're dealing with quotients here, this reminds me of the isomorphism theorem. I have, in my book:

> Theorem: Every module over $R$ is isomorphic to a quotient module of a
>   free module over $R$

however there's no mention of with which object the quotient is.

Comment: $0\to A \to X \to X/A \to 0$ is split exact since $X/A$ is free (projective). From there it is a general statement  see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_lemma

Comment: Is it the case that $R$ is a PID?

Comment: @JJR I appreciate your answer but I cannot use exact sequencex yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f:B\longrightarrow X/A$ be the inclusion map. Since $h:X/A\longrightarrow X,$ and $g\circ h= f,$ then it follows that $h$ is an injective map (on $B$ at least). Put $h(B)=B'\subset X.$ Denote the span of $B'$ as $X'\subset X.$

Since  $h$ (as a linear map) is uniquely determined by how it is defined on  $B,$ then $h$ is an injective linear map. Then it certainly follows that $A\cap X'=0,$ else $h$ wouldn't satisfy the universal property.

We only need to show that $A+X'=X.$ To do so, pick any element in $v\in X.$ Consider now $v+A,$ the image of $v$ in $X/A.$ Due to the lifting, $h,$ there is a corresponding element $v'=h(v+A).$ It is clear too that $v'+A$ and $v+A$ represent the same coset, and so there exists some $a\in A$ so that $v'+a=v\in X.$ Since $v\in X$ was arbitrary, then we have shown that $X'+A=X,$ and thus $X=X'\oplus A.$